# how to achieve Google Play Music-like button look in my app?

Tags: android, styles

Hi I have been inspired by a Google Music app and been trying to achieve the same effect on the button when it is pressed. The shot will help u understand:

[image]

SO here the button gets that semi-transparent nice-looking effect. Unfortunately, i ve gone nowhere with it, i just managed to similar button but now it doesnt change color when i press it? Im really stuck and need help, im a novice in android dev, i have been trying selectors but when I set a selector to button background the app fails at runtime.
Here is a screenshot of my button:

[image]

For this button, to achieve the shadow I used the `card_background.9.png` file so it also changes the whole button background to white. I assume what is why the button looses the default pressed state.

XML code for the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Facebook"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom button with creating a custom style. In this style you can define different images for different button states (for example enabled, pressed...). Take a look at this [tutorial](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=8BED36512503CA63614CA9237248CBE7?recipeId=3307).